# Button Click by Name in Safari with Applescript

Tags: javascript, safari, applescript

I'm following a tutorial at: http://cubemg.com/applescript/how-to-click-a-button-on-a-web-page-with-applescript/

I am trying to make a script that loads a webpage and clicks a button by name.
My code looks like this

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do JavaScript "window.open('http://www.google.dk')" in document 1   
end tell
to clickName(theName, elementnum)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName(‘" & theName & "‘)[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickName
clickName("btnI", 0)
```

It just opens the page in safari and does nothing. Applescript keeps telling me "missing value" but it does that even when i run the code only for opening the specific website.
I have created a similar code for entering values into a form, but the result is the same.

Does anyone have the same problem?

I have checked the names of the button multiple times and tried it on multiple different sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo/bug in your script. This line is using "smart quotes" for the single quotes. This:

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName(‘" & theName & "‘)[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1
```

should be this

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('" & theName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1
```

Plus, you really need to put a delay after you load the web page, to make sure the element is loaded.

Comment: Thanks! That was amazing! I copypasted part of the code from the tutorial. I would never have discovered that

Comment: How can this be done with System Events? Upload button doesn't work this way when selecting file sadly.